# Why do some medications have HCl?

Tags: medications

I have seen a lot of medications including a few that I take for certain situations. 1 of the medications that I occasionally take is Benadryl. The main component of this is Diphenhydramine HCl. I have always wondered why this and some other medications have HCl mixed with the main ingredient. I mean, HCl can dissolve pretty much anything given the time and is why people with Achlorhydria(total absence of HCl in their stomach) have iron deficiency anemia. HCl makes iron better absorbed.

But why do some medications have HCl in them if the HCl could potentially dissolve all the medication and make it useless(chemical burn to get medication useless)? Is it to increase the amount that is absorbed just like it does with iron?

Comment: See [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20309/why-formulate-drugs-as-hcl-salts-when-hcl-is-in-stomach-acid) on Chemistry.SE.

Comment: It's interesting that, thought that question is almost 2 ½ years old, it still hasn't been marked as answered.

Comment: @BillOertell That's because the OP returned for the last time the next day around 11:00 am, which was 3 hours before it was answered, so she never saw the answer. That happens to a lot of questions on SE.